# How to get better error messages when developing flutter for web

Tags: flutter-web

When trying to start a working flutter mobile app as web app I got the error message:

[SEVERE ] 16:37:02 - XXX                   - MissingPlug…ime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15

and found nothing helpfull in the web on that error.

But I found out that it is because we are using the package_info package which is not compatible with flutter for web.

Is there any way to get better error messages - maybe telling the file/line with the problem or anything which makes it easier to find the problem?